# Using Kinect to control the motion of the turtlebot based on body movements

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, gazebo, navigation, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I'm new to ROS and Gazebo. I am working on a project to get the turtlebot to move around based on the movement of the arms as detected by the kinect. How do i go about this process. How do i assign the turtle bot navigation depending on the movement of the arm.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55241/using-kinect-to-control-the-motion-of-the-turtlebot-based-on-body-movements/) by [Maverick](https://answers.ros.org/users/4209/maverick/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have been working on exactly what you are asking for a while. Its [here](http://code.google.com/p/hri-ros-pkg/). I programmed it for the static gestures made by right hand (simply for different angles made b/w the arm and forearm). I made a map of a house, found a key point for each of the rooms and associated a gesture to a key point. So, when you stand in front of the turtlebot and strike a gesture, it goes to the room which is associated to the gesture. read_user_pose.cpp extracts the gestures, the key points in the map are stored in goalpoints.inputfile and navigation code is key_based_nav.cpp. Sorry, the stack is quite old and has few bugs, you cannot use the code directly. I will be uploading the refined version in GIT shortly. But I am sure that will help you.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2013-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bit-pirate](https://answers.ros.org/users/62/bit-pirate/) on 2013-02-17**:
Cool! I would love to see this program as an app for turtlebot! What about adding it to [turtlebot_apps](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps), once you are done updating the code?

**Comment by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) on 2013-02-17**:
That's an idea! Thanks ;-)